# Adding and deleting random entries from a list inside another list in Python?

Tags: python, list, random

So, I have a few lists and would like to add random entries from those lists inside another list. This list should later on be randomly cleaned by a few entries.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.choice()` and do something like this:

```
import random
for i in range(4): # add 4 entries from l2 and l3
    l.append(random.choice(l2))
    l.append(random.choice(l3))
```

Hope this helps.